# Why could `RowPitch` be impossibly large after a `Map` call?

Tags: direct3d11

I am trying to save a screenshot.

First make a staging texture by copying the original texture's description with

```cs
CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
```

and calling `CopyResource`

Next in a different thread I am calling `Map` (`MapSubresource` in SharpDX), and the call succeeds, however in the returned struct `RowPitch` has seemingly impossible value: 0xc204a428 (that's over 2GB).

Why am I getting an obviously invalid value?

Comment: Two possible reasons. (1) Multi-threading issue. Device contexts are not thread safe. While you calling map/unmap subresource from a background thread, you must use some lock to prevent the device context to be used from any other thread. A good way to diagnose is pass `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag when creating the device, check “enable native debugging” in visual studio, and run your app with debugger attached, you should see these diagnostic messages in the ”output” window of the IDE. (2) Another possible reason is bug in SharpDX library.